# Multiplying csv value - TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, csv

So, part of the code I am writing for my uni work requires me to multiply ranking points on a csv list by the difficulty of the tournament.

I have tried everything that I know but I keep getting *TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*

This is what I have at the moment:

```
import csv
class Opener:

    with open("DADSA 17-18 COURSEWORK A RANKING POINTS.csv", "r") as csv_file3:
        next(csv_file3)
        rp = csv.reader(csv_file3)
        ranking_points = []
        for rowrp in rp:
            if len(rowrp) != 0:
                ranking_points += [rowrp]
```

[List with the ranking points(left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqRcH.png)

*Download csv file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tga4h6mxug2rlj4/DADSA%2017-18%20COURSEWORK%20A%20RANKING%20POINTS.csv?dl=0)*

```
tourn=input("What is this tournament: ").upper()

def tournament(tourn):
    rp0 = Opener.ranking_points[0][0]
    multiply = 0
    for line in rp0:
        if tourn == "TAC1":
            multiply = 2.7
            rp0 *= multiply
        elif tourn == "TAE21":
            multiply = 2.3
            rp0 *= multiply
        elif tourn == "TAW11":
            multiply = 3.1
            rp0 *= multiply
        elif tourn == "TBS2":
            multiply = 3.25
            rp0 *= multiply
    return rp0
tournament(tourn)
```

*TAC1*, *TAE21*, *TAW11* and *TBS2*, are the name of the difficulty levels.

I hope one of you can help me with this, I've tried a few things that I found here but at the end it all comes down to the same error.

EDIT: 
The error that I put initially was from a previous run where I tried something else.

The full error from this code looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Transferencias/DADSA/Tournament.py", line 62, in

```
tournament(tourn)
```

File "D:/Transferencias/DADSA/Tournament.py", line 50, in tournament

```
rp0 *= multiply
```

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Without trying to run your code, I expect your error is coming from the line `rp0 *= multiply`.  You should have included more context for the error message.  `multiply` is your float.  I'm guessing the format of *rp0* is different than what you expect.  Try printing out its value and checking its type.  I think you'll find that *rp0* is an array or list (since it's a row from a CSV).  You may need to use the `map()` command instead of simple multiplication.

Comment: rp0 = Opener.ranking_points[0][0] gives me one value
you can not iterate trough one value. you need a list

Comment: Also, that `Opener` class definition is rather strange.

Comment: @Gary02127 I am new to python, any chance you could make an answer on how I could use **map()**

Comment: @swisswiss I intended to iterate through the csv column

Comment: @PM2Ring maybe it is a bit unnecessary, but there is more to it in the actual code, but this was the only part that was relevant to the question.

Comment: @Sanfer - Actually, in this situation, a list comprehension would be simpler than a map() call. `[i * multiply for i in rp0]` should do the trick, unless there is some surprise in the items of rp0. If there is, you may have to do a little bit of a massage to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take special note to the line

```
ranking_points += [[float(i) for i in rowrp]]
```

you have to create a float list otherwise you will have trouble in multiplication with other floats

```
import csv
class Opener:

    with open("DADSA 17-18 COURSEWORK A RANKING POINTS.csv", "r") as csv_file3:
        next(csv_file3)
        rp = csv.reader(csv_file3)
        ranking_points = []
        for rowrp in rp:
            if len(rowrp) != 0:
                ranking_points += [[float(i) for i in rowrp]]


tourn=input("What is this tournament: ").upper()

def tournament(tourn):
    # global Opener.ranking_points[0][0]
    rp0 = Opener.ranking_points
    # print(rp0)
    multiply = 0
    for line in rp0:
        print(line[0])
        if tourn == "TAC1":
            multiply = 2.7
            line[0] *= multiply
        elif tourn == "TAE21":
            multiply = 2.3
            line[0] *= multiply
        elif tourn == "TAW11":
            multiply = 3.1
            line[0] *= multiply
        elif tourn == "TBS2":
            multiply = 3.25
            line[0] *= multiply
    return rp0

print(tournament(tourn))
```